# Hand creating a password using website name as salt

Tags: security, passwords, cryptography

A while ago I read a blog on a  method of creating passwords.
It was something along the lines of:

1) create a template password, with usual mix of chars, cases, etc.
2) use the website name the password is for, as a salt
3) run it through a algorithm by hand that returns a new password

This seems like a great idea to me, and I want to look into it more.
My question is, does anyone have a link to a proper article or blog, that describes this method in more detail?
Or is anyone more familiar with this technique than I am?

Comment: Requests for learning material are considered off-topic.

Comment: What about using `yourstrongpassword + htts://yourwebsite` and use some hasing algorithm, like SHA1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the article you are speaking of, and it does describe the creation and application of the 'salt' (as abused as the term is in this case).

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-create-strong-password-that-you-can-remember-easily/

Personally my recommendation is to generate most of your passwords, and look into a password manager like LastPass/Keepass/etc. the old definitions of strong password no longer apply, with Rainbow Tables, enhanced dictionaries, and failing last-generation hashing algorithms (MD5, SHA1, etc).

Comment: This is indeed the exact article I had in mind, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at http://peebs.org/2012/06/09/heres-how-to-salt-your-own-passwords-and-prev/ for this.